# Get the price when exit/close strategy

Tags: pine-script

It can use strategy.opentrades.entry_price(0) to get the price when strategy entry.
But how to get the price when strategy exit/close?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, similarly, there is

```
strategy.closedtrades.exit_price(strategy.closedtrades - 1)
```

For example:

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © vitruvius

//@version=5
strategy("My strategy", overlay=true, margin_long=100, margin_short=100)

longCondition = ta.crossover(ta.sma(close, 14), ta.sma(close, 28))
if (longCondition)
    strategy.entry("My Long Entry Id", strategy.long)

shortCondition = ta.crossunder(ta.sma(close, 14), ta.sma(close, 28))
if (shortCondition)
    strategy.entry("My Short Entry Id", strategy.short)

exit_price = strategy.closedtrades.entry_price(strategy.closedtrades-1)
plot(exit_price, "", color.red, 2, plot.style_circles)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This is what I looking for. I don’t know why I didn’t find this keywords. Thanks again!

Comment: But here is a question, there will be NaN at the first exit, how should I get every exit price?

Comment: Why would it be NaN? As soon as the position is closed, it will be a valid number. See my edit.

Comment: I let strategy.closedtrades.exit_price(strategy.closedtrades-1) in the comment of strategy exit. I think here is the problem? example as below:   strategy.exit("Close Long","Open Long",stop=CloseCondition,comment="LC"+str.tostring(strategy.closedtrades.exit_price(strategy.closedtrades-1)))